# Angular httpClient not performing network request

Tags: angular, httpclient

in one of my Service classes I try to perform an API request to my firebase authentification API. The Service class Looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  private apiKey: string = '[API-Key]';

  private userToken: string;

  login(email: string, password: string): Observable<HttpResponse<string>> {
    console.log('Ich wurde ausgeführt.')
    return this.httpClient.post<string>(`https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=${this.apiKey}`, 
    {email: email, password: Password, returnSecureToken: true}, {observe: 'response'})
    .pipe(
      tap(
        response => {
          console.log(response); 
          this.userToken = response.idToken;
        }, 
        error => {
          console.log(error);
          return error;
        }
      )

    )
  }

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
}
```

In the same Moment, if the request executes successfully I want to use the reponse from the httpClient post request to asign the token value provided by the Response to the `private userToken: string` variable within the Service class.

To conclude the howl Story again: my Problem is that this Network request the the firebase Auth API isn't fired and I don't know why. Also I think that my Code to proceed the Response is quite well and could be improved.

Can anyone help me? Thank you very much and have a nice day!

Comment: you need to subscribe to it to perform the request

Comment: Did you import httpmodule in your module

Comment: Without httpmodule import, the problem wouldn't be "the request isn't fired", it would be "build error".

Comment: @jcuypers I tried several times to subscribe to it, but it didn't work because I return an obejct from type observable and that doesn't work together with a subscription. Don't Forget I want to asign the value in the Service itself. So my solution is, that I don't return the reponse as an observable, but I subscribe to the repsponse in the Service itself and that seems as it works. Thank you very much for that hint!

Comment: Doesn't really matter _who_ subscribes, but without any subscription, the request won't be triggered.

Comment: @andreasteich yes, the answer give is like a generic solution, you could as well apply it in your service.  doesn't matter.

Comment: @jcuypers Thank you very much! So my solution works, but now I face the Problem that in my subscribe method I try to Access a specific field from my Response. For example ..`.subscribe(data => console.log(data.body.idToken)` But for some reason that's not possible, because this property doesn't exists my IDE says. So how can I Access a specific property from the reponse I  get?

Comment: just check in the debugger (network tab) of your browser (ctrl-shift-I) what the response looks like (and if you get anything back at all), another way is to console.log(JSON.stringify(data)) to better understand what your are getting back.

Answer (score 0):

like in your component you want to use it

```
import { OnInit, Component } from '@angular/core'

export class Component implements OnInit { 

   constructor(private authService: AuthService){}

   ngOnInit() {
      this.authService.login(param1, param2).subscribe(result => {}, err => {});
   }


}
```